# Время работы алгоритма(реальное и выводимое)

Tags: алгоритм, время, скорость

Есть алгоритм, время работы которого я засекаю с помощью функции clock, пишет, что алгоритм выполнился за 7.118 секунд, хотя на деле с момента начала компиляции до момента вывода результата на экран прошло >15 секунд, так вот, вопрос, на что уходит остальное время? и если можно, то где можно найти информацию по этому поводу?

Comment: на что уходит остальное время?     `с момента начала компиляции ` - на компиляцию, видимо

Comment: с момента нажатия на кнопку Локальный отладчик Windows, если я что-то не так сказал

Comment: После нажатия на кнопку, вероятно, происходит компиляция, линковка, и запуск исполняемого файла. Вы даже не сказали, какой язык и какая среда используется.

Comment: язык C++ среда разработки: Microsoft Visual Studio

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду разбираться в вами указанных терминах

Comment: Да и код хорошо бы посмотреть. Может у вас какой-то код исполняется ещё до начала и/или после конца вычисления времени выполнения.